# Slicing on scan output with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

If I want to slice after a scan operation in TensorFlow.

But I just get strange results with TensorFlow:

```
k = 10
x = 2
out = tf.scan(lambda previous_output, current_input: previous_output * current_input, 
          tf.fill([k], x), initializer=tf.constant(1)) 

result = out[-1] # slice with tensorflow - don't work

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(sess.run(out)[-1]) # works but all values are computed and stored in an np array
    print(sess.run(result)) # don't work???
```

I get as output:

```
1024
3
```

The second value is obviously wrong and random (sometimes 0 or other values).
So my question is why? The analog code in Theano e.g. works and Theano can do some optimization when querying just the last element of the output tensor.

Comment: This seems like a bug, filed issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4604 A workaround is to use regular indices (out[9] works, but out[-1] doesn't)

Comment: This seems to be fixed in latest version btw (nightly wheel)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.